# Find the max and min of $(a \mathbf{x} + c)(b \mathbf{x} + d)$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector with linear constraints.

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, bilinear-form, quadratic-programming

Suppose there is a $n$-dimensional column vector $\mathbf{x}$, and an objective function $f(\mathbf{x}) = (a \mathbf{x} + c)(b \mathbf{x} + d)$, where $a$ and $b$ are $n$-dimensional row vector; $c$ and $d$ are scalers.

We want to find the max and min of $f(\mathbf{x})$ given the following constraints:

$\mathbf{x}$ is constrained by $\{x_i | -1 \le x_i \le 1 \}$, and $0 \le a \mathbf{x} + c \le 1$ and $0 \le b \mathbf{x} + d \le 1$.

Since $a^T b$ has a determinant of 0, $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x}$ is neither convex or concave, and it cannot be solved by a general convex optimization. Is there a way to solve this problem efficiently, or programmatically?

Thank you

Comment: How does $a^Tb$ having determinant $0$ imply that $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x}$ is neither convex nor concave? Depending on whether $a, b$ and $\mathbf{x}$ are row or column vectors, the expression $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x}$ might not be defined at all.

Comment: In addition, it is unclear how your question is about quadratic programming. The objective of quadratic programming is to minimize $\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^TQ\mathbf{x} + c^T\mathbf{x}$ where $Q$ is a real symmetric matrix.

Comment: $\mathbf{x} Q \mathbf{x} > 0$ is proven to be equivalent to convexity, while $\mathbf{x} Q \mathbf{x} < 0$ is proven to be concave. I think this is also how quadratic programming  checks if a function is convex.

$\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x}$ is the multiplication of dot products against $a$ and $b$. As long as $a$ and $b$ are not at the same line, there will be an $x$ that makes $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x} < 0$ and another $x$ makes $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x} > 0$, so it is nether concave or convex.

Comment: For QP, $f(x_1) + f(x_2) - 2 f(\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2})$ is equivalent to $(x_1 - x_2)^T Q (x_1 - x_2)$. Given the $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x}$, even at the same point, one direction will be concave, and another direction will be convex.

Regarding the QP question, I don't know if there is an extension to tackle the Q that is not symmetry?

Comment: @AugustinPan How about $\mathbf{x}^T a^T b \mathbf{x} = \frac12\mathbf{x}^T (a^T b + b^Ta) \mathbf{x}$.

Comment: Thank you, @RiverLi. This works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For maximum, it is equivalent to the convex optimization problem below
\begin{align*}
 &\max_{x, u, v} \quad \sqrt{uv}\\
 &\mathrm{s.t.}\quad\ ax + c \ge u, \\
 &\qquad\quad bx + d \ge v, \\
 &\qquad\quad u, v \ge 0, \\
 &\qquad \quad 0 \le ax + c \le 1, \\
 &\qquad\quad 0\le bx + d \le 1, \\
 &\qquad\quad -1 \le x_i \le 1, \forall i.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, this will work

Comment: @AugustinPan You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the answer of @RiverLi,

we can take the log to make the problem concave:

$$ f(x) = \log(ax + c) + \log(bx + d) $$

subject to the linear constraints given in the same question. Then maximize the above objective function.

This method can also be extended to the multiplication of multiple linear queries.

---

Regarding the min of the function, there are many ways to approximate the max (min) of a convex (concave) function. Here is [one algorithm](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219190161V) I have found to be popular.

Comment: For minimum, one way is to use SDP relaxation. But I don't know if it works.